# How to compute the sub arrays in node/express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my schema

```
{
    "categoryname": {type: String},
    "subcategory": [
        {
            "subcategoryname": {type: String},
            "product": [
                {
                    "productname": {type: String},
                    "subproduct": [
                        {
                            "itemcode": {type: String},
                            "itemname": {type: String},
                            "itemdescription": {type: String},
                            "itemimgurl": {type: String},
                            "mainprice": {type: Number},
                            "offerprice": {type: Number},
                            "status": {type: Boolean},
                            "unit": {type: String},
                            "itemprice":[
                                {
                                    "itemname" :{type: String},
                                    "unit": {type: String},
                                    "offerprice": {type: Number},
                                    "mainprice": {type: Number},
                                    "notifystock": {type: Number},
                                    "stock": {type: Number},
                                    "itemstatus":{type: Boolean},
                                    "itemimgurl": {type: String}
                                }
                            ]  
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I access the `product`  and `subproduct` arrays?

I'm trying to update only `productname` in `product[]` in this way, but I'm getting error

```
menu.update(
{"_id":request.params.id,
"subcategory._id": request.params.subcategoryid,
"subcategory.$.product._id": request.params.productid},
{$set:{"subcategory.$.product.productname": request.body.productname}},
{safe: true, upsert: true})
```

I'm getting error like this

```
{
  "name": "MongoError",
  "message": "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: subcategory.$.product.productname",
  "driver": true,
  "index": 0,
  "code": 16836,
  "errmsg": "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: subcategory.$.product.productname"
}
```

And how can I push and update only `subproduct` data?

Comment: Is the name correct, in schema it is `subcategory ` and in query is `subcat `

Comment: As it would not be readable to everyone I have changed it to subcategory in schema. I will edit in the post immediately. Thanks for notifying me

Comment: I would suggest you to change your Schema, and make products Schema, with the group key embedded. Querying the schema provided above is very not recommended...